# How to give name to topics created using LDA?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, nlp, text-mining, topic-model

I have categorized 800,000 documents into 500 categories using the Mahout topic modelling.

Instead of representing the topic using the top 5/10 words for each topics, I want to infer a generic name for the group using any existing algorithm.
For the time being, I have used the following algorithm to arrive at the name for the topic:

For each topic

- Take all the documents belonging to the topic (using the document-topic distribution output)
- Run python nltk to get the noun phrases
- Create the TF file from the output
- name for the topic is the phrase (limited towards max 5 words)

Please suggest a approach to arrive at more relevant name for the topics.

Answer (score 7):

I can suggest several papers on this topic:

- Automatic Labelling of Topic Models
- Automatic Labeling Hierarchical Topics
- Representing Topics Labels for Exploring Digital Libraries

You can find more by looking at their citations.

Comment: thanks... i will check the papers (in particular the first one)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to dig into much NLP in that task, I suggest you to generate a set of most frequent NGrams (of lengths 2-5) from your documents and find the most distinct ngrams for each category using TF*IDF metric as sense importance of a particular ngram (normalizing measure by word count) and selecting those Ngrams that are used in a particular category and are not (or rarely) used in others.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. But initially i had tried with NGrams(3 words) with tf-idf approach. But the label generated were jot that meaningful. Can you suggest any NLP approach which will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using word vectors to average the top N words in a topic and then using the cosine similarity to find the closest word in the corpus?

Just a quick and dirty an idea...

Comment: i have tried this approach.Also added tf-idf so that the words are unique for topic. But the result is not that encouraging

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of trying this myself but won’t bother now.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas you'll often see..

- Generate a list from Wikipedia titles, extract keyphrases, predict the related wikipedia pages and use the keyphrases.
- Generate a hand-labeled dataset.
- Use a graph populated with topics and the relations between words and topics to predict the most likely topics
- Abstractive summarization and keyphrase extraction